# Having trouble installing Paddle Module

Tags: python

I'm receiving an error when i try to install a .whl file:

```
$ pip install paddlepaddle-1.8.5-cp27-cp27m-win_10_6_intel.whl
```

`ERROR: paddlepaddle-1.8.5-cp27-cp27m-win_10_6_intel.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

I am running windows 10, the latest version of pip, and python 3.9.1
I'm in the correct directory when I run it but I am not sure why it is doing this.
the main goal is to install paddle, and $ pip install paddle didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look like you are trying to install cp27 compatible version which is Cpython 2.7 and you have 3.9.1 in your system, that's why you are getting that error.
try this:

> pip install paddlepaddle-1.8.5-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

It should work, because AMD supports Intel architecture.
but in case if this doesn't work try to create venv and install python2.7 and do your work.